# how to specialize templated member functions of non-templated classes?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

suppose I have a file alpha.h:

```
class Alpha {
public:
    template<typename T> void foo();
};

template<> void Alpha::foo<int>() {}
template<> void Alpha::foo<float>() {}
```

If I include alpha.h in more than one cpp file and compile with GCC 4.4, it complains there are multiple definitions of `foo<int>` and `foo<float>` across multiple object files.  Makes sense to me, so I change the last two lines to:

```
template<> extern void Alpha::foo<int>() {}
template<> extern void Alpha::foo<float>() {}
```

But then GCC says:

> explicit template specialization
>   cannot have a storage class

ok... so how am I supposed to do this correctly?  I'm worried that C++ doesn't allow what I'm trying to do in the first place, in which case is there a good idiom that will accomplish the same thing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use inline keyword

```
template<> inline void Alpha::foo<int>() {}
```

alternatively, provide implementation in separate cpp file

Answer (score 6):

You can forward declare as well as the inline option:

```
// .h
template<> void Alpha::foo<int>();

//.cpp
template<> void Alpha::foo<int>() {}
```

Answer (score 4):

From the ODR point of view, a fully (explicitly) specialized template is no longer a template, so it is subject to the same ODR principles as a non-template entity of the same kind. (There are some exceptions from that rule, I believe, but it is good enough for our purposes).

In your case, for ODR purposes a fully specialized function template is an ordinary function. So, as an ordinary function it should be *declared* in the header file and *defined* in one and only one implementation file.

Answer (score -1):

No separate declaration or inline keywork is required. PF below working code.

```
#include<iostream>

class temp
{
public:
    template <class T>
    T add1(T a, T b)
    {
            return (a + b);
    }
};

template<>
std::string temp::add1<std::string>(std::string aa, std::string bb)
{
    return aa+bb;
}

int main()
{
    temp *tc = new temp();
    std::cout << tc->add1<float>(5.7, 4.5) << std::endl;
    std::cout << tc->add1<std::string>("my ","program") << std::endl;
}
```

output is :

> 10.2
>
> my program

Comment: Surely, if you have everything in one file... But that's not OP's question, he has problems with multiple objects files. I.e. he wants to know how to make it work when the header file is used in several compilation units.